# What is the ACM Queue for operations research (or sub-disciplines)?

Tags: academia, industry, journals

In his [2016 Usenix presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADvBM2j51U0) Bryan Cantrill highlighted an issue with how conferences work in operating system research. He mentioned an alternative format called [Queue by ACM](https://queue.acm.org/author_guidelines.cfm) which he describes as leading practitioners are gathered and in loose atmosphere discuss what kind of articles they want to see and then people are found to work on these topics, the paper is peer reviewed by other practitioners and guaranteed publication once it is satisfactory.

[image]

Are you aware of such "journals" in OR or sub-fields of OR?